# xargs cp how to use asterix?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, xargs, cp

I'm trying to copy files by mask with preserving folder structure(using `--parents`), I can't use `cp -r --parents` or `rsync` directly because of `argument list too long` error.

```
ls folder1/folder2/ | head | xargs -I {} cp -r --parents folder1/folder2/{}/neutral* neutral_data/
```

but seems asterix symbols don't work here as expected, instead I get few errors like:

```
cp: cannot stat 'folder1/folder2/folder3/neutral*': No such file or directory
```

What is the proper way of using asterix symbol in this context or maybe any other method to solve this problem?

**Update:**

Based on this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5247/221416 I tried

```
ls folder1/folder2/ | head | xargs -I {} sh -c cp -r --parents folder1/folder2/{}/neutral* neutral_data/
```

but it gives error:

```
cp: missing file operand
```

Comment: Use `rsync` instead of `ls`, `xargs`, `cp`.

Comment: I can't use `cp -r --parents` or `rsync` directly because of `argument list too long` error.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Using `ls` is almost always a bad strategy, because of spaces and other special characters in file/folder names, etc. There should be no problem at all doing that with `rsync`. What exactly are your criteria? Which files/folders should be included or excluded? How much of the source directory structure do you want to reproduce in the destination (the whole source path, or only the last part(s) of it)? You can use `--relative` with rsync to determine exactly what part of the source path needs to be preserved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
ls folder1/folder2/ | xargs -I {} bash -c "cp -r --parents folder1/folder2/{}/neutral* neutral_data/"
```